# Sort list of dicts by sub-key value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have following list of dictionaries:

```
test_list = [
        {'sr_no': 1, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Salmon & Brown Rice'}, 
        {'sr_no': 2, 'recipe_type': 'Side Dish', 'name': 'Cupcakes'}, 
        {'sr_no': 3, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Whole chicken'}, 
        {'sr_no': 4, 'recipe_type': 'Desserts', 'name': 'test'}
    ]
```

I need to sort it on base of `name` index value alphabetically. As below:

```
test_list = [
        {'sr_no': 2, 'recipe_type': 'Side Dish', 'name': 'Cupcakes'}, 
        {'sr_no': 1, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Salmon & Brown Rice'}, 
        {'sr_no': 4, 'recipe_type': 'Desserts', 'name': 'test'}
        {'sr_no': 3, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Whole chicken'}, 
    ]
```

I have searched this on SO and google but find no definite answer.

Comment: `from operator import itemgetter; test_list.sort(key=itemgetter('name'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `key` function that returns `name` from each dict to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> test_list = [
...         {'sr_no': 1, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Salmon & Brown Rice'},
...         {'sr_no': 2, 'recipe_type': 'Side Dish', 'name': 'Cupcakes'},
...         {'sr_no': 3, 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'name': 'Whole chicken'},
...         {'sr_no': 4, 'recipe_type': 'Desserts', 'name': 'test'}
...     ]
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(test_list, key=lambda x: x['name'].lower()))
[{'name': 'Cupcakes', 'recipe_type': 'Side Dish', 'sr_no': 2},
 {'name': 'Salmon & Brown Rice', 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'sr_no': 1},
 {'name': 'test', 'recipe_type': 'Desserts', 'sr_no': 4},
 {'name': 'Whole chicken', 'recipe_type': 'Main Dish', 'sr_no': 3}]
```

Comment: thanks but  the sorted result is not as required. Name is not sorted alphabetically. Whole chicken should come at last position.

Comment: @Simer Oops, didn't notice you had names starting with upper & lower case. That can be mitigated by converting the name to lower (or upper) case which I've modified the answer to do.